# error 1 inconsistent accessibility:

Tags: c#

It's my first time using Stackoverflow as asker at least, and english is not my native language so please sorry my english.

I get this error

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than field 'Agenda.Form1.listaPersonas'

I actually have found it in other questions, but all of the answers say that parameters must be public and this is something that I don't understand. I'm still a student, and I have learnt that field's visibility have to be private and accessors public. Anyway, I have tried to put them private but I'm still having the same issue.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Agenda
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Persona> listaPersonas = new List<Persona>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    } 

    class Persona
    {
        private string nombre;
        private string apellidos;
        private string telefono;
        private DateTime fechaNac;

        public Persona(string nom, string ape, string tel, DateTime fecNac) {
            this.nombre = nom;
            this.apellidos = ape;
            this.telefono = tel;
            this.fechaNac = fecNac;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Persona
```

means the class is internal only.
You'll have to make it `public` to make it accessible to your other code

simply add the public keyword to it:

```
public class Persona
```

Comment: No   means the class is private only  the class is internal not private

Comment: yep true. Typing faster than thinking sometimes suxx ;)

Answer (score 0):

you  have to add

```
public  class Persona

  {
```

your constructor is defined  `public` creating  an instance of the class will not be possible as the default modifier is `internal` when no modifier is applied

[**From MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

*`Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.`*